# React Native Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, react-native

Guys in this question I asked about I can't get any more style property suggestions in react-native style components in vs code. so please give me a solution or any extensions.
Platform: Vs code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL0rr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native